# SSH FTP Upload to FTP server

Tags: ssh, ftp

I am trying to upload a large file from my linux server via SSH to a ftp server. (i only have ftp access to this remote server)

Here is the command i am trying to do

> put myfile.zip

Result:

> 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for myfile.zip

The transfer starts but upon getting to about 10gb uploaded, i get this error. and the file deletes itself from the ftp server.

> 451 Transfer aborted. Input/output error

I was wondering if there is an alternative or if i am doing something wrong? or even if there is a way i can resume the upload..

Answer (score 0):

The protocol has no limitations, but most servers have default upload limits out-of-the-box. There are also timeouts on concrete servers applicable.

You said you can SSH to it, didn't you? So what about `scp` to it, or to mount remote folder as `sshfs` aka `sftp`?